# Xcode 11.5 doesn't support iOS 13.6?

Tags: ios, xcode

Attempting to connect via USB or wireless doesn't work. Xcode reports:

```
The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPad mini (5th generation) is running iOS 13.6 (17G68), which is not supported by Xcode 11.5.
```

Anyone know of a work-around/update?

Comment: Update to Xcode 11.6

Comment: Thank you, I missed that update.

Comment: Download the ios device support from this link and add it to xcode ios devices support folder https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport
if you can not  update the xcode yet.